# Xamarin - Storyboard - how to make nice UI

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am trying to build a nice looking UI with Xamarin storyboard designer for Visual Studio, and I am struggling to find documentation on how to do it.

How do you make a background for an entire view? 
How do you control which elements are on top of other ones?

In Xcode on xib interfaces there is something like the document outline where you can drag and drop items to control which are infront of other ones. It something like this I am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add ImageView as the first control on your view and set it's image property using this code.

```
img.Image=UIImage.FromBundle("Images/logo_login.png");
```

And then place all the other controls above it.